# How to choose monochrom/color option in CUPS printing

Tags: printing

I want to print pages from command lines (normally PDF files).  I use de `lp` command:

```
lp mydoc.pdf
```

I found several options (one sided vs double-sided, N-up,...) but could not figure how to specify printing in color or grey scale.
Is it possible?

Edit: Here is the output of the command suggested by Rinzwind:

```
sudo grep -i color HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M277dw_295BCF_.ppd
*ModelName: "Color LaserJet MFP M277dw"
*Product: "(Color LaserJet MFP M277dw)"
*NickName: "Color LaserJet MFP M277dw"
*ShortNickName: "Color LaserJet MFP M277dw"
*ColorDevice: True
*MediaType StationeryColored/stationery-colored: "<</MediaType(StationeryColored)>>setpagedevice"
*OpenUI *ColorModel/Mode de couleur: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *ColorModel
*ColorModel Gray/Niveaux de gris: "<</cupsColorSpace 18/cupsBitsPerColor 8/cupsColorOrder 0/cupsCompression 0>>setpagedevice"
*ColorModel RGB/Couleur: "<</cupsColorSpace 19/cupsBitsPerColor 8/cupsColorOrder 0/cupsCompression 0>>setpagedevice"
*DefaultColorModel: RGB
*CloseUI: *ColorModel
```

I tried

```
lp -o ColorModel=Gray file.pdf
lp -o ColorModel=Color file.pdf
```

but did not notice any difference.

Afterwards, I used the second approach, using lpoptions:

```
lpoptions -l
PageSize/Media Size: Letter Legal Executive FanFoldGermanLegal 4x6 5x8 *A4 A5 A6 B5 B6 Env4x6 Oficio 195x270mm 184x260mm 7.75x10.75 Postcard DoublePostcardRotated Env10 EnvMonarch EnvISOB5 EnvC5 EnvDL Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
Duplex/Two-Sided: *None DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble
InputSlot/Paper Feed: *Auto Tray1 Tray2 ManualFeed
HPOption_Duplexer/Duplex Unit: *True False
HPPJLColorAsGray/Print Color as Gray: on *off
HPRGBEmulation/RGB Color: *DefaultSRGB PhotoSRGB Adobe VividSRGB HPRGBEmulationNone
HPEdgeControl/Edge Control: HPEdgeControlOff Light *Normal Max
HPGeneralHalftone/Halftone: *Smooth Detail
HPTextNeutralGrays/Text Neutral Grays: *Black ProcessBlack
HPGraphicsNeutralGrays/Graphics Neutral Grays: *Black ProcessBlack
HPPhotoNeutralGrays/Photo Neutral Grays: Black *ProcessBlack
HPPJLEconoMode2/EconoMode: on *off
MediaType/Media Type: *Unspecified Plain HPEcoSMARTLite HPLaserJet90 HPColorLaserMatte105 HPPremiumChoiceMatte120 HPBrochureMatte150 HPCoverMatte200 HPMattePhoto200 HPPremiumPresentationGlossy120 HPBrochureGlossy150 HPTrifoldBrochureGlossy150 HPBrochureGlossy200 Light6074 Intermediate8595 MidWeight96110 Heavy111130 ExtraHeavy131175 HeavyGlossy111130 ExtraHeavyGlossy131175 CardGlossy176220 ColorLaserTransparency Labels Letterhead Envelope HeavyEnvelope Preprinted Prepunched Colored Bond Recycled Rough HeavyRough OpaqueFilm
```

I noticed the line

```
HPPJLColorAsGray/Print Color as Gray: on *off
```

So, using

```
lp -o HPPJLColorAsGray=on file.pdf
```

I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General advice: look in the PPD file for the printer.

```
grep -i grey /etc/cups/ppd/{printer}.ppd
grep -i gray /etc/cups/ppd/{printer}.ppd
```

(I would assume it will be gray ;) )

it will show you what the name of the option is.

Then this could work but it depends on the printer ...

```
lp -o ColorModel=Gray mydoc.pdf
```

As an [alternative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18449/10017) you can also change [lpotions](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpoptions.html) in the configuration file before printing but that also requires you to reset it back to color every time. `lpoptions -l | grep Color` will show how to set it for gray.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  After some search, I could get it to work (see my edits)

Comment: Cool! glad you got it working.